# Vertical Align Input Inside a Section

Tags: html, css

I've searched and tried a lot of CSS codes. I also, vertically aligned something before. Tried everything I know, couldn't done this time.

I've a form. Inside this form, two sections. Inside sections, one input (each). All of these covered by article.

How to make this inputs vertically align in sections?

HTML

```
<article>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="blabla">
<div id="side1">
<input type="image" name="side1" src="path.png">
</div>
<div id="side2">
<input type="image" name="side2" src="path2.png">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</form>
</article>
```

CSS for this guys

```
article #side1{
    width:47%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 750px;
}

article #side2{
    width:47%;
    padding:1%;
    float:right;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height: 750px;
}

#side1 input, #side2 input{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried display table, table-cell combination. inline-block, vertical-align, fixed height etc etc etc. So don't mind my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1:

The `table` > `table-cell` trick with `vertical-align:middle` doesn't work on inputs directly. Just wrap your inputs in a div and then center those divs using that trick.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/dhr4hpo7/1/

HTML: (notice the .input div)

```
<div id="side2">
    <div class="input"><input type="image" name="side2" src="path2.png" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
article #side1, article #side2{
    width:47%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 750px;
    display:table;
    border: 2px dotted grey;
}
#side1 .input, #side2 .input{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:20px;
}
```

### Method 2:

Here's another demo using `position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%`

and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

and no extra div wrapping necesseary

http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/dhr4hpo7/4/

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer. I don't want to give fixed height to input, so I didn't. But still, it worked for me. But I want to ask, do I have to use fixed height for sections? If yes, think about this scenario. Side one has 100x200 image, side two has 100x250 image. In this scenario, both sections must be 250 px height. Let's say side one has 250x550 image, side two has 225x225 image. In this scenario, both sections must be 550 px height. Decide which one is longer and fix height related to longer one. Can I do this with CSS or should I use JS? Note that contents are dynamic.

Comment: Don't use js. Css can do it. If that's the case, put the inputs in the same table. You have to have the both cells inside the same table. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/dhr4hpo7/5/

Answer (score -1):

You need to put `<br/>` tags after each `<div>` tag. You can stack multiple `<br/>` tags to create spaces inbetween:

```
<article>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="blabla">
      <div id="side1">
        <input type="image" name="side1" src="path.png">
      </div><br/>
      <div id="side2">
        <input type="image" name="side2" src="path2.png">
      </div><br/>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </form>
</article>
```

If that doesn't work, try putting the `<br/>` tags in different places, such as after the `<input>` tags.